# Charts asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to implement a chart on view getting values from database

Code:

```
 @{
var db = Database.Open("aspnet-NewApp-20150923010220");
var data = db.Query("SELECT Name, Price FROM Product");
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Product Sales")
    .DataBindTable(dataSource: data, xField: "Name")
    .Write();
}
```

But when I try to use `database.open` and `db.query` it says me cannot resolve symbol, how can I resolve this?

Comment: You're reading the [W3Schools ASP.NET WebPages tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_chart.asp). WebPages != MVC. That code is not going to work like that in an MVC view.

Comment: I google alot and I not find charts working with mvc with data from database :/

Comment: do you want to use WebPages?

Answer (score 2):

If you require quick chart creation, use the [ChartHelper](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart#Saving_a_Chart)

Pass the data from your controller action as your `model` to the `View`.

Something like:

```
 public class Product
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
 }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DrawChart()
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Price FROM Product", con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   products.Add(new Product{ Name = reader.GetString(0), Price = reader.GetString(1)});
                }
            }
        }

        return View(products);
    }
```

Customize the above as required. (there are alternate ways to get the data ofcourse)

This is an example `View`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@{

var myChart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 300, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
    .AddTitle("Product Sales")
    .AddSeries("Default",
               xValue: Model, xField: "Name",
               yValues: Model, yFields: "Price")
    .Write("png");
}
```

For more control over your chart use: 
[System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How to display record on each bar?